# Swift5 Extra argument 'completionHandler' in call error with session.dataTask

Tags: swift, swift5, completionhandler, urlsession

I am trying to make a some weather app
but there is some problem
The error is "Extra argument 'completionHandler' in call"
what should i do for solve it ??
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMpsn.png)

```swift
    import Foundation
    
    struct WeatherManager {
        let weatherURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=sdfkjskfjsfjskflskflsjklfjf&units=metric"
        
        func fetchWeather(cityName: String) {
           let urlStirng = "\(weatherURL)&q=\(cityName)"
            performRequest(urlString: urlStirng)
        }
        
        func performRequest(urlString: String) {
            //1. Create a URL
            if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                
                //2. Create a URL Session
                let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
                
                //3. Give the session a task
                let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: handle(data:response:error:))
                
                //4. Start the task
                task.resume()
                
            }
        }
        
        func handle(data: Data?, response: URLSession?, error: Error?) {
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: please post code ... instead of image ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following code:

```
func performRequest(urlString: String) {

    //1. Create a URL
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        
        //2. Create a URL Session
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        //3. Give the session a task
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: handle)
        
        //4. Start the task
        task.resume()
    }
}

func handle(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {

}
```

For `response` you need to pass an `URLResponse` instead of an `URLSession` to `handle` and you don't have to write the parameter names, because you are passing your `handle` function as an argument to `dataTask`.